# Adding specific ticks with date labels from a date variable on x-axis

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, label, timeserieschart

I have a df with two variables:

```
Observations: 342
Variables: 2
$ date   <date> 2016-04-02, 2016-04-03, 2016-04-04, 2016-04-05, 2016-04-06, 2016-04-07, 2016-04-08, 2016...
$ visits <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
```

I want to plot visits against date, but on my x-axis i wish to see some specific ticks for dates when some special events happened (to show more visits were present immediately after). The code now shows me some some dates of course, but i want some dates added, let's say "2016-08-10" and "2017-01-25".

How can i extend my code to show additional ticks with labels?

```
p = ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = visits)) + 
    geom_line(colour = "purple")

p
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scale_x_date`:

```
set.seed(666)
df = data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2016/4/1"), as.Date("2016/4/30"), by = "day"), visits = round(runif(30, 0, 30)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = visits)) + 
geom_line(colour = "purple") + 
scale_x_date(breaks = c(as.Date("2016-04-10"), as.Date("2016-04-20")))
```

[image: plot]